# Why isn't the <a tag not muting the video?

Tags: javascript, html

I need a Mute/Unmute button and an  tag that can only mute the sound of a video when clicked.
The mute/unmute button works fine, but the <a tag doesn't do anything

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
      <div>
        <video src="video.mp4" id="vid"autoplay muted loop></video>
        <div class="controller">
            <button onclick="muteUnmuteVideo()" type="button">Mute/Unmute sound</button>
            <a href="#" onclick="stopSound()">Stop Sound</a>
           
        </div>
      </div>

      
      <script>
        var my = document.getElementById("vid");
        const playVideo=() => {
            my.play();
        }
        function muteUnmuteVideo(){
            my.muted = !my.muted;
        }
        let exitvid = document.getElementById("vid");
        function stopSound(){
            exitvid.muted = false;
        }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: IMO `a` elements are meant to move users to a new page. Use `button` for interactions like play/pause. -- Also the `stopSound` function does not stop the audio.

Comment: You forgot to call the function, `onclick="stopSound()"`

Comment: @evolutionxbox i know but i have to use <a in this situation. I am making a lightbox and the <a tag is supposed to close the lightbox and return to the normal page.

Comment: @CristianLeciu please make sure the code is a [mcve].

Comment: @ThumChoonTat thanks, i edited the post now, its still not working

Comment: _"i know but i have to use <a in this situation. I am making a lightbox"_ - so is the problem with the exact code we currently see above - or in _combination_ with your lightbox script? Have you verified (via a simple console.log inside), whether your `stopSound` function executes at all?

Comment: @CBroe ok i checked the console, the function executed but it said false instead of true. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the js code
try to use built in video tag you can get the controllers by default

```
<video controls muted width="80%" height="50%">  
  <source src="https://assets.mixkit.co/videos/preview/mixkit-stars-in-space-1610-large.mp4/" type="video/mp4">  
 </video>
```

Comment: I'm currently designing for mobile and the controllers are way too small, and i only need the mute button. I solved the problem, it had to be exitvid.muted = true; instead of false, but thank you for the response.

Comment: Please actually *answer* the question in the answers section.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).